# subspace generated by vectors in matlab and the projection matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

How can I have the subspace generated by given vectors in Matlab?

For example, I have vectors `$v_1 ,...,v_n$`; what is the span of `v_i`'s in Matlab?

And how can I have the matrix that projects every vector on this subspace?

I mean, how can I give some vectors to Matlab and get the projection matrix on the span of vectors?

Can you please shoe me the code?
I am really new to Matlab and in need of your help.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) to get an orthogonalization of the columns of `v`. Then the projection matrix is Q * Q':

```
[Q,R] = qr(v, 0); % "economy size" QR decomposition
proj_v = Q * Q';
```

Comment: The basis is `Q`, the projection matrix is `Q*Q'`.

Comment: what is the span of v_i's in Matlab?

Comment: The column space of matrix Q forms an orthonormal basis that is equal to the span of the v_i's.